# AdventureWorks Query

Tags: sql, adventureworks

In AdventureWorks 2008, what are some other (better) ways of writing this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.CustomerID,  c.CustomerType, 
ISNULL(s.Name, p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName) AS Name  

FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader o

INNER JOIN Sales.Customer c
ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID

LEFT OUTER JOIN sales.Individual i
ON i.CustomerID = o.CustomerID

LEFT OUTER JOIN sales.Store s
ON s.CustomerID = o.CustomerID

LEFT OUTER JOIN Person.Contact p
ON p.ContactID = i.ContactID 

ORDER BY CustomerID
```

Preferably with the ability to support additional CustomerTypes.

Results look like:

```
   CustomerID   CustomerType    Name
    697            S            Brakes and Gears
    698            S            Western Bike Supplies
    699            S            Sensational Discount Store
    700            S            Underglaze and Finish Company
    701            S            Future Bikes
    11000          I            Jon Yang
    11001          I            Eugene Huang
    11002          I            Ruben Torres
    11003          I            Christy Zhu
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  I see nothing wrong with the query you've written.

Comment: The query does work, but I feel it is a sloppy way of doing it. I was hoping there is a more efficient way. Especially if there are more than (2) CustomerTypes. Would I use multiple ISNULL's?